# Heroku node_modules not found

Tags: node.js, rest, express, heroku

I have a REST API built using Node.js and Express.js. The api works when running locally (tested via postman) and also works with `heroku local web`.

The problem comes when I deploy it to Heroku. As far I know, it doesnt find `node_modules` folder. here is the error when viewing Heroku logs.

```
2018-08-05T23:06:22.543693+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the rest-api@0.0.1 start script.
2018-08-05T23:06:22.543859+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-08-05T23:06:22.551894+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-08-05T23:06:22.552047+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-08-05T23:06:22.552153+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-08-05T23_06_22_545Z-debug.log
2018-08-05T23:06:22.633382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-08-05T23:06:22.844536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I logged to Heroku bash using `heroku run bash` and see all my files including `node_modules` is there. Tried running running `yarn dev` in the bash (my start script) here is what i get

```
~ $ yarn dev
yarn run v1.9.4
$ nps dev
/bin/sh: 1: nps: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here is my `package.json` file [Package.json](https://gist.github.com/HamidHabib/96c2bfffeea1d786817a404e5ee55a87)
Here is my `package-scripts.js` file [package-scripts.js](https://gist.github.com/HamidHabib/4e2535e000a654d93564298f1296f6a9)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I literally tried every stackoverflow suggestion but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Set `NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false` in Heroku's config variables

Comment: No luck, still getting `nps` not found

Answer (score 1):

Check if your package.json file has the dependencies added. I faced the same problem cuz I didnt have the dependencies.

Comment: This better served as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Set `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` and try. Heroku will strip out the packages declared under devDependencies before deploying the application. nps module under devDependencies will not be available.